# how to collapse all previous nested view when onclick current view in android

Tags: java, android

my layout code is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/invitation_single"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="5dp"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invitation_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invitation_place"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hidden"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yesbutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nobutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="No"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonmaybe"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="Maybe"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
```

In above code "invitation_single" is root layout  and "hidden" is nested layout.

my programming code is below

```
final LinearLayout first = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);
 final LinearLayout second = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);
 first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.invitation_single:
 second.setVisibility(second.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
   break;

                    }

                }

            });
```

My root layout(invitation_single) have two "textviewes" and nested layout(hidden) have three "buttons".When i am on tap my root layout the nested layout visible immediately below the root layout.In my output i have two events when i am on tap first event the nested layout(buttons) visible similarly if i am on click second event i need to hide the nested layout of previous event and show the nested layout of current event(that means i need to visible the nested layout of current event and close all other nested layouts).how can i achieve this help me.

Comment: did the answer below help solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help, please let me know so that I can delete it to save people from wasting their time looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` is tricky. When the view is gone, it does not simply come back, it can mess up everything. One simple solution to get it back is to re-call `setContentView` after changing from `View.GONE` to `View.VISIBLE`. Make sure you save the contents of your views before calling `setContentView` and then refresh them with the saved values after calling `setContentView`.

Some people choose to call `onCreate(null)` which also does the job. In both case you need to save and restore the contents of your views.

Another alternative is to use LayoutInflater.

Example (not tested)

```
    first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.invitation_single:
                    if(second.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                        second.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else{
                        // save the content of your views
                        setContentView(....); // call as you called in onCreate or whatever
                        // restaure the content of your views.
                    }
                break;

            }

        }

    });
```